# C# write in textbox in a web from url

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I'm working on a project in c# .net where I have a website, on the page is a textbox

I have some qr codes that link to this page
when a particular qr code must fill in a text box.

it is possible to write a ULR that can automatically fill in the textbox

ex  page.com(insert to tbxOne:"123")

Comment: We need more information. Is this a Winforms, WPF or ASP.Net application?

Comment: it is a web form asp.net yes. I do not have any qr code yet, but will make them based on whether it is possible to do it with a url link

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the QR codes?

Without code I can't be too much help but you could try come if the following things.

Document.getelementbyid(#id).innerhtml("text");

This will allow you to set the text of an element on the webpage.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx